# responding to form submission without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog, window, onsubmit

I have a form which submits data to db... i want the response to appear on the page like a pop-up and when the user clicks the button, it takes him to the specified url attached to the button...

this is my form

```
<form method="post" class="myform" id="ajaxForm" action="php/processForm.php">

   <label for="Surname" id="title" class="one"> Surname: </label>
   <input name="Sname" type="text" required placeholder="Surname" />
   <div class="clear"></div>

   <label for="Fname" id="title">First Name: </label>
   <input name="Fname" type="text" required placeholder="First Name" />
   <div class="clear"></div>

   <label for="Email" id="title">Email address:</label> 
   <input name="Email" type="email" required placeholder="someone@yourdomain.com" />
   <div class="clear"></div>

   <label for="CompanyName" id="title">Company name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="CompanyName" placeholder="Company Name" />
   <div class="clear"></div>

   <label for="number" id="title">Phone Number: </label>
   <input name="number" type="tel" required placeholder="+23480123456789" />
   <div class="clear"></div>

   <label for="category" id="title">Category:</label> 
   <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="Job Category..e.g web design" />
   <div class="clear"></div>

   <label for="Job-Description" id="title">Tell us what you want:</label>
   <textarea name="Job-Description" required >Delete this and write a comprehensive description of what you want... </textarea>

   <button type="submit" name="submit" clas="signup-button"> Submit </button>

</form>
```

my php script

```
$sname=$_POST['Sname'];
$fname=$_POST['Fname'];
$email=$_POST['Email'];
$company=$_POST['CompanyName'];
$phone=$_POST['number'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$feedback=$_POST['Job-Description'];



  $sql="INSERT INTO $table_name ( sname, fname, email, company, phone, category, jobDescription) 
VALUES('$sname', '$fname', '$email', '$company', '$phone', '$category', '$feedback')";

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

if($result){
  echo      'success';
} else {
  echo 'failed';
}
```

and the jquery

```
   $( "#ajaxForm" ).submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'php/processForm.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  $('#ajaxForm').serialize(),
        success: function(response) { 
          if(response == 'Success') {  
          $('section').append('<div id="message">Thank you for requesting our service, We will get back to you within 48hours....' +
                              '<div type="button" class="theButton"><a href="index.html"> OK </a> </div>' +
                              '</div>');
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

right now it just seem to ignore the jquery and just write Success on the screen, am new to this...
how can i make the div with the id of "message" appear like a pop-up?

Comment: `success` != `Success`. Scripting and programming languages are case sensitive.

Comment: it didn't make any difference... it still ignores the jquery

Comment: Given the fact that it's just writing `Success` to the screen, my initial assumption is that the form is still submitting to the server and redirecting, which means that your ajax function is never firing, which means that your submit function isn't firing, which means that jQuery isn't loaded on the page likely

Comment: i moved the jquery code directly into the page that has the form, now the form submits no values to the db even after filling the form...